# No tun device in lxc guest for openvpn

Tags: openvpn, lxc

I am trying to set up an openvpn server inside a lxc guest. However, it seams there is no tun device available in the container.

Starting openvpn inside the container gives me this error:

```
Tue Sep 18 13:04:18 2012 Note: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)
Tue Sep 18 13:04:18 2012 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Tue Sep 18 13:04:18 2012 /sbin/ifconfig  10.6.0.1 pointopoint 10.6.0.2 mtu 1500
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFDSTADDR: No such device
: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFMTU: No such device
Tue Sep 18 13:04:18 2012 Linux ifconfig failed: external program exited with error status: 1
Tue Sep 18 13:04:18 2012 Exiting
```

In my containers config, I see the following:

```
#tun
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:200 rwm
```

I'd assume this enabled tun devices for the container, but modprobe tun gives me another error:

```
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.2.0-30-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
```

I'm assuming I am missing some permission or something in my container. Can someone tell me what it is?

Comment: Does `/dev/net` exist?

Comment: No, /dev/net does not exist either.

Comment: This solution worked for me: https://superuser.com/questions/1202749/how-to-run-openvpn-in-a-lxc-container-inside-debian-host/1205662#1205662

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not familiar with [lxc](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/), but try the following commands:

```
# mkdir /dev/net 
# mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200 
# chmod 666 /dev/net/tun
```

Comment: and in lxc config the following line:
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:200 rwm

Comment: @apagr Doesn't work anymore on Ubuntu 14.04...

Comment: Works with lxc turnkey openvpn on proxmox 4.3

Comment: works for proxmox7, no need to modify the config file for the lxc.

Answer (score 8):

The answers above don't actually work now with current versions of `lxc`. Manually creating a character device with `mknod` has no effect - the device is not visible inside the container. Use of the `autodev` functionality in `lxc` is required.

- For systems with `systemd` See ***LXC Config*** on the [Arch Linux
  Wiki for OpenVPN in Linux Containers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Openvpn_in_linux_containers#LXC_config):

`lxc.mount.entry = /dev/net dev/net none bind,create=dir`

`lxc.cgroup2.devices.allow = c 10:200 rwm`

- In an Alpine Linux container (without `systemd`) I use:

`lxc.cgroup.devices.deny = a`

`lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:200 rwm`

`lxc.hook.autodev = sh -c "modprobe tun; cd ${LXC_ROOTFS_MOUNT}/dev; mkdir net; mknod net/tun c 10 200; chmod 0666 net/tun"`

The order is important - the `deny` must be first.

Comment: Actually on a Debian 10 unprivileged LXC container and an Ubuntu 19.10 host, the only thing I needed to to is to add `lxc.mount.entry = /dev/net dev/net none bind,create=dir` in the container config file, mentioned in your link and with a similar solution here: https://superuser.com/questions/1202749/how-to-run-openvpn-in-a-lxc-container-inside-debian-host/1205662#1205662

Comment: For information, when using a Kali Linux LXC container on a Debian 11 host, it only worked when using the full solution of your link:
`lxc.mount.entry = /dev/net dev/net none bind,create=dir
lxc.cgroup2.devices.allow = c 10:200 rwm`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to quanta's answer.
Also make sure you have this line in the lxc config:

> mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200

This is the right syntax:

```
#tun
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:200 rwm
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by our hosting provider EURO-SPACE, these are steps how to enable TUN/TAP on Proxmox LXC containers:

1. Make sure your container is PRIVILEGED, if not, then make a backup of the container, then restore it and check "Privileged Container".
2. Shutdown container and edit its configuration file located under /etc/pve/lxc/CTID.conf (CTID is the ID of your container)
3. Add following lines at the end of file:

   lxc.cgroup.devices.allow: c 10:200 rwm

   lxc.hook.autodev: sh -c "modprobe tun; cd ${LXC_ROOTFS_MOUNT}/dev; mkdir net; mknod net/tun c 10 200; chmod 0666 net/tun"
4. Save configuration file and start the container.
5. Make sure TUN is enabled by running following command:

   cat /dev/net/tun

This should output the following:

cat: /dev/net/tun: File descriptor in bad state

Now you can run VPN.