# How to create /dev/tun device inside unprivileged LXC container?

Tags: openvpn, lxc, tun

This question is similar to [No tun device in lxc guest for openvpn](https://serverfault.com/questions/429461/no-tun-device-in-lxc-guest-for-openvpn) . The LXC has evolved and the unprivileged LXC containers were introduced recently that offer another layer of security against breaking the jail.

I need to create an OpenVPN server inside one of the unprivileged container. I don't know how to let the container create a private tun network device.

I did append `lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:200 rwm` to the `~/.local/share/lxc/mylxc/config`.

After starting the container, `mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200` returns `mknod: '/dev/net/tun': Operation not permitted` inside the container.

I use a vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 64bit as host and a container created with

```
lxc-create -t download -n mylxc  -- -d ubuntu -r trusty -a amd64
```

Did anyone managed to get `/dev/tun` device running under unprivileged LXC?

Comment: For information, to make openvpn work in an unprivileged LXC container, I had to add `lxc.mount.entry = /dev/net/tun dev/net/tun none bind,create=file` to the container config file, like described here: https://superuser.com/a/1205662/130915
Then, I ran openvpn as root with sudo inside of the container.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly add the CAP_MKNOD [capability](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) to your [container](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/lxc.container.conf.5.html).

> ```
>   lxc.cap.keep
>           Specify the capability to be kept in the container. All other
>           capabilities will be dropped. When a special value of "none"
>           is encountered, lxc will clear any keep capabilities specified
>           up to this point. A value of "none" alone can be used to drop
>           all capabilities.
> ```

You could also try to automate this (if you happen to use `systemd` inside the container) using:

> ```
>   lxc.hook.autodev
>           A hook to be run in the container's namespace after mounting
>           has been done and after any mount hooks have run, but before
>           the pivot_root, if lxc.autodev == 1.  The purpose of this hook
>           is to assist in populating the /dev directory of the container
>           when using the autodev option for systemd based containers.
>           The container's /dev directory is relative to the
>           ${LXC_ROOTFS_MOUNT} environment variable available when the
>           hook is run.
> ```

which can point to a script running `mknod`.

Using [`docker`](https://docs.docker.com/) this is very easy to accomplish. By default, containers are [unprivileged](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration).

In this example, I'm pulling a `trusty` container from the registry:

```
sudo -r sysadm_r docker pull corbinu/docker-trusty
Pulling repository corbinu/docker-trusty
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for corbinu/docker-trusty:latest
```

And I'm starting it in interactive mode informing about the capability I need inside:

```
sudo -r sysadm_r docker run --cap-drop ALL --cap-add MKNOD \
  -i -t corbinu/docker-trusty bash
root@46bbb43095ec:/# ls /dev/
console  fd/      full     fuse     kcore    mqueue/  null     ptmx     pts/     random   shm/     stderr   stdin    stdout   tty      urandom  zero
root@46bbb43095ec:/# mkdir /dev/net
root@46bbb43095ec:/# mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
root@46bbb43095ec:/# ls -lrt /dev/net/tun
crw-r--r--. 1 root root 10, 200 Apr  6 16:52 /dev/net/tun
```

As opposed to:

```
sudo -r sysadm_r docker run --cap-drop ALL \
  -i -t corbinu/docker-trusty bash
root@9a4cdc75a5ec:/# mkdir /dev/net
root@9a4cdc75a5ec:/# mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
mknod: ‘/dev/net/tun’: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: I believe, what docker calls "unprivileged" is quite different from what it means in LXC parlance: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7906 . It seems that Docker still don't support the unprivileged containers. It doesn't necessarily invalidate your answer - I'll check `CAP_MKNOD` after work.

Comment: Can you give me please a little pointer on how to change the capability of the unprivileged container? At least a correct phrase to Google?

Comment: Adding the `lxc.cap.keep  = CAP_MKNOD` to config makes error `Simultaneously requested dropping and keeping caps`. I checked all recursively added configs (`ubuntu.userns.conf`, `ubuntu.common.conf` and `common.conf`) and found only one line with `lxc.cap.drop`: `lxc.cap.drop = mac_admin mac_override sys_time sys_module`. But that is irrelevant isn't it?

Comment: `You need to explicitly add the CAP_MKNOD capability to your container.` How to do that for an existing LXC Container?

Comment: @PhilippLudwig https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422879/2248946